# Failing to print negative values using C++ in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

The VS Code version is x64-1.63.2. The compiler is g++ (version 6.3.0). I use C++ (GDB/LLDB). OS version: WIN10
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xUmK.jpg)

VS Code can only show the positive value (22) but cannot show any negative value no matter by `cout` or `printf`. But when I run it in the terminal of VS Code, the negative values can be shown normally.

[image: Screenshot of terminal]

How could this happen and how should I resolve it? Also, I wonder why the results are shown in the debugging console instead of the terminal when I choose running WITHOUT debugging (Ctrl+F5)?
Below is my directory.
[image: My directory]

This is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = -10, i2 = 42;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;          // -10
    std::cout << 2 * i + i2 << std::endl; // 22
    std::cout << 5 * i + i2 << std::endl; // -8
    std::cout << -10 << std::endl;        // -10
    printf("%d", i);                      // 10
    return 0;
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json file

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

tasks.json file

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe 生成活动文件",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - 生成和调试活动文件",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "为 gdb 启用整齐打印",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe 生成活动文件"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Don't show images of text. Copy-paste text (especially code) *as text* into your questions. Please [edit] your question to improve it. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please do not use Screenshots for code, if people try to recreate the issue, they want to copy and paste the program.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What are your compiler settings? Which version are you using?

Comment: The VS Code version is x64-1.63.2. The compiler is g++ (version 6.3.0). I use C++ (GDB/LLDB). OS version: WIN10

Comment: Actually, I think it must be the problem of my configuration of the IDE rather than the C++ code because I can run normally on the terminal.

Comment: I think you're using MinGW, as that's what the screenshot says. Anyhow, maybe you should share the configuration setting.

Comment: Resolved after I reinstalled MinGW and VS Code